# LibreOffice Calc - Split one column into two

Tags: libreoffice, charset

I'm moving user/customer details from my mother's old web store. Only problem is that exported .csv-file has name details in the same column like this:

```
[        col A     ]
lastname, firstname
lastname, firstname
lastname, firstname
```

I would like to move them into separate columns like this, I just don't know how :P :

```
[ col A ] [ col B]
lastname   firstname
lastname   firstname
lastname   firstname
```

Also, how to convert symbol � to what it should be (ÄÖ in this case)?

using LibreOffice on Mac

Comment: Data -> Text to Columns. Regarding the Symbol: Check the encoding of the CSV data.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/10/easily-splitting-one-column-into-two-or-more-columns-at-the-separators-of-your-choice-in-openofficeorg-calc-spreadsheets.html) is of help.